# Detect if component has NgModel set in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I would like to know if a component has its `[(ngModel)]` set.

I'm creating a typeahead component and would like to know if the ngModel is set to the element.

Something like this:

my-form.component.html

```
...
<my-custom-typeahead [(ngModel)]="somevariable" name="someinput1"><my-custom-typeahead>

<my-custom-typeahead name="someinput2"><my-custom-typeahead>
...
```

my-custom-typeahead.component.ts

```
@ngModule({
    ...
    selector: 'my-custom-typeahead',
    ...
})
export class myCustomTypeaheadComponent{
    // I would like to know if the ngModel was set in the component
    // something like @Host('my-custom-typeahead').has2wdb('ngModel')
}
```

I think using @Host is not the answer, but it was the way I could explain it more.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Maybe add some code.. Can't follow..

Comment: @mxii I've edited my question and provided an example of what i'm trying to do. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement `[(ngModel)]` you have to implement its interface `ControlValueAccessor`.

This interface has the function `writeValue(val: any)`..

If this function is called, you received a value via `[(ngModel)]`. :)